# How can I replace ALL instances of a string in the previous command in Bash?

Tags: bash

If I have just entered the following command in Bash:

```
echo foo
```

I can change foo to bar by typing:

```
^foo^bar
```

Which results in the following command being executed:

```
echo bar
```

Now if I enter:

```
echo foo foo
```

Is there a way to change both instances of foo to bar just by using the caret (`^`) operator?

Additionally, are there man pages for shell operators like `^`? `man ^` results in "No manual entry for ^".

Comment: Thanks for the answers, was hoping for a way to use the ^ syntax for duplicates since it is something I can remember more easily but looks like I will have to memorize the line noise version.

Comment: It might be easier for you to remember the "line noise" version if you also think of `^string1^string2` as already being equivalent to `!!:s/string1/string2/`.

Comment: @mattjames if you want something easier to remember, you can check out my answer, which is less "line noise"-y

Answer (score 74, accepted):

That particular feature is called *quick substitution*; its documentation can be found in the [Event Designators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) section of the Bash Manual.  You can't do what you want with quick substitution; you'll have to resort to something slightly more verbose:

```
!!:gs/foo/bar/
```

Comment: Trailing slash was not needed for me on OSX: `!!:gs/foo/bar`

Answer (score 41):

Nor sure how to do it with caret substitution, but here's how you do it with history:

```
!!:gs/foo/bar/
```

Let me break that down:

> !! - reruns the last command.  You can also use !-2 to run two commands ago, !echo to run the last command that starts with echo
>
> :gs says to do a global (all instances) search/replace.  If you wanted to just do replace the first instance, you would use ':s'
>
> Finally, /foo/bar/ says to replace foo with bar

Answer (score 27):

Try:

```
^foo^bar^:&
```

As you know `^foo^bar^` performs just one substitution, and the `:&` modifier repeats it.

Comment: This will execute two substitutions but not a global substitution.

Comment: I discovered that you could pass in multiple ":&" modifiers to the caret substitution. So the ":&" means again, and ":&:&" means again twice, and so on. (Repeating :& for every repetition will become tedious, and I'm glad to learn about !!:gs//.

Answer (score 6):

Caret substitution and other similar shortcuts are found in the **Event Designators** subsection of the **HISTORY EXPANSION** section of the `bash(1)` man page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something less difficult to memorize that accomplishes the same thing as the above `!!:gs/foo/bar/`, you could always create a function in your .bash_profile start-up script. I chose `replace()`.

```
replace() {
    eval $(echo $(fc -ln -1) | eval "sed 's/${1}/${2}/g'") #compact form
}
```

OR, Less convolutedly

```
replace() {
    string=$(fc -ln -1) #gets last command string
    repcmmd="sed 's/${1}/${2}/g'" #build replacement sed command from fn input
    eval $(echo $string | eval $repcmmd) #evaluates the replacement command
}
```

Then the replace all can be made with

```
echo foo foo
replace foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^word^  ........... erase word
^word^^ ........... delete everything until the end of the line
```

Comment: These both do the same thing for me: remove only word from the command.

Comment: Same here. `% echo "word word word word word"
word word word word word
% ^word^^
echo " word word word word"
 word word word word
`