# git show HEAD^ doesn't seem to be working. Is this normal?

Tags: git, bash, zsh

I'm using Zsh and and trying to run git show for a project to see my revision history.  If I do

```
git show HEAD
```

it works fine showing me my last commit, however the following commands don't work

```
[master↑5⚡]:~/project $ git show HEAD^ 
zsh: no matches found: HEAD^
[master↑5⚡]:~/project $ git show HEAD^^
zsh: no matches found: HEAD^^
```

However this does work

```
git HEAD~1
```

Am I doing something wrong here with `git show HEAD^^`?

git version 1.7.4.5

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The carat (`^`) has [special meaning in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2149482/78845) and Zsh.

You'll need to escape it or quote it:

```
% git show HEAD\^

% git show 'HEAD^^'
```

Comment: (But honestly, in most cases it's easier to use `~` syntax unless you need something other than the first parents.)

Comment: TIL about the `HEAD~` syntax.  Blew my mind, thanks @Amber!

Answer (score 38):

Instead of escaping or quoting the caret, you could just tell `zsh` to stop bailing on the command when it fails to match a glob pattern. Put this option in your `.zshrc`:

```
setopt NO_NOMATCH
```

That option stops `zsh` from aborting commands if glob-matching fails. `git show HEAD^` will work properly, and you needn't escape the caret. Furthermore, globbing and the `^` [event designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators) will still work the way you expect.

To answer dolzenko's question in comments, you can get `git log ^production master` (which is, coincidentally, also exactly what git's 'double dot' syntax does: `git log production..master`) to work by disabling extended globbing:

```
setopt NO_EXTENDED_GLOB
```

Of course, you might actually rely on extended globbing and not know it. I recommend reading about [what it does](http://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37/ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion/) before disabling it.

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work for things like, e.g. `git log ^production master --no-merges`?

Comment: @dolzenko: Edited the answer. If you don't want to turn off extended globbing, just use the double dot syntax.

Comment: Working link for extended globbing article: https://www.refining-linux.org/archives/37-ZSH-Gem-2-Extended-globbing-and-expansion.html

Answer (score 9):

You can also use noglob.

```
% noglob git show HEAD^
```

(or make an alias for `noglob git`)